# What's the meaning of "The agent quotes the bid price ..."?

Tags: financial-literacy, financial-statements

I'm studying an article about High-frequency trading. I'm very new at financial market so maybe my question is very simple.

In the article writers said  "The agent quotes the bid price...". What's the meaning of "quotes the bid price" for a trader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the location or financial market so here's how it works in the US.

The SEC requires that all exchanges provide NBBO (National Best Bid and Offer) quotes which denotes the best bid and ask prices for each security.  The bid is the highest price that a buyer is currently willing to pay and the ask is the lowest price that a seller is willing accept.

Who the agent is in your quote is unknown.  You'll have to check the context of that statement to see if NBBO fits in or whether agent represents something else in your article.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very useful. I have another question, according to your answer what's the meaning of "bid and ask spreads"?

Comment: The bid/ask spread is the difference between the bid price and the ask price.